# PrettyPhoto opening Youtube video/images in new tab instead of lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube, prettyphoto

I'm using the prettyPhoto plugin to create a lightbox effect, but it simply doesn't work. I followed the steps from the site (im not that experienced with javascript etc), but I cant get it to work. When clicking the link, it simply opens up the file in a new tab, wether it's an image or a youtube video.

Can anyone please help me out with this? Ive been on it for a day now and I still cant get it to work.

Here the links to Jquery, the prettyphotolibary:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("a[rel='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        });
    </script>
```

The link to the stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" />
```

This is the link where I want the lightbox to open in:

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7_LMMB3w5M" rel="prettyPhoto"
title="test">CLICKME FOR LIGHTBOX</a>
```

Am I missing something here? I think its maybe in conflict with some other plugins I have installed, is that possible? Here to view the full website: [www.romyvanalebeek.com](http://www.romyvanalebeek.com)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I just removed the  `$(document).ready(function(){`

So now I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    });
</script>
```